# In {N}, can I animate image backgroundPosition?

Tags: nativescript

In {N}, can I animate image backgroundPosition?

The think the answer will be no.

In that case, anyone try doing the animation using `setInterval()` or something similar - will that work (and looking relatively smooth)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
.thing{
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-WeXXx2gmVlY/VNiy484uYoI/AAAAAAAAAsU/XeTgzY9k-Us/s1600/Gambar-Keren-Unik-DP-BBM-Terbaru9.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-position:-300px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    -webkit-transition:background-position 1s ease;
}

.thing:hover{
    background-position:0px;
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfXSs/882/
You should be more spesific

Answer (score 0):

{N}+Angular2 You can do this:

In HTML:

```
<StackLayout class="bg" [style]="'background-position:'+translateValue+'  
'+translateValue+';'">
    <Label [text]="translateValue"></Label>
<StackLayout>
```

In CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("res://bg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

In some.component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public translateValue:number = 0;
  constructor() {
      setInterval(()=>{
        this.translateValue++;
      },50);
  }
}
```

I know this is not a good solution, but it works.